# Would a consumer know if the RESTful URL is OData based or the simple RESTful api url? Does it matter?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

If I create a simple RESTful web API in c# and one OData RESTful API and host them. Would the consumer know which one is OData based and which one is a simple one? Does it matter to them?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you expose them: if you let users send an ODATA query then yes the user will know. If it's under the hood then no, the customer doesn't need to know. It's a bit like asking whether your users can guess whether your datastore is SQL or something else

Comment: Great. What I actually meant was that the structure of URL matters? does it change if I use a simple or OData? that was my concern